# on_key_press() events blocking on_mouse_press() an on_mouse_motion() events for 1 second

Tags: python, pyglet

So I'm developing a small game in Pyglet and I have across this weird behavior which I don't know how to solve. It seems like a Pyglet bug, but it's weird that I cannot find others users reporting this problem.

The problem is that after a key is pressed, if I left click right after the key press, the event is ignored. This is repeatable, always. What's funny is that if I right click, the event is always working fine. Only left click is the problem. Also on_mouse_motion() is blocked for 1 second after any key is pressed. If I don't press any keyboard keys, all mouse events work just fine.

I have tested this with Pyglet versions 1.3.0, 1.4.10 and 1.5.11 and all have the same behavior. I also tested this on 2 different computers and behavior is the same. I also tried with Vsync ON and OFF and with mouse exclusive to pyglet window. Using Windows 10 and Python 3.7.4-64b.

Here is a simple code to reproduce the problem, just press a key and then left click within 1 second:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    print('A key was pressed')

@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    print('Mouse event') 

pyglet.app.run()
```

EDIT: The problem is the Synaptics touchpad which is configured to disable the touchpad during typing on laptops.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Mac with Python 3.9.1 and pyglet-1.5.13.

Comment: Can't reproduce with Windows 10 Python 3.9.0 and pyglet 1.5.13.

Comment: Just upgraded Anaconda to latest, upgraded Python version to 3.9.1 and Pyglet to 1.5.13 and behavior is the same... are you using Anaconda or plain Python ?

Comment: ... plain Python (Visual Studio Code)

Comment: uninstalled Anaconda and fresh installed just Python 3.9.1 an Pyglet 1.5.13 and problem is still there... will try on a 3rd computer tomorrow... both laptops I tried today have an i5 intel CPU, maybe this matters ?

Comment: problem was laptop touchpad, external mouse works... thanks for your inputs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is the Synaptics touchpad which is configured to disable the touchpad during typing on laptops:

https://superuser.com/questions/399341/touchpad-does-not-respond-when-i-am-holding-key-on-the-keyboard

I connected an external mouse to the laptop and the problem is gone.